# How to modify a MP3 metadata and save by Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to achieve below goals:

- Read a MP3 metadata
- Modify the encoding of that metadata (if I could modify the content of that metadata, that would be better)
- Save the modification to that MP3 file

All these operations could be based on native Node.js (without browser). Is there any module provide such function or I can develop based on?

Comment: Reading metadata: https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-id3

Answer (score 13):

For those coming to this question through Google, there is a node module that can do this, both read and write metadata:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/ffmetadata

Comment: Its worth noting that this has a dependence on ffmpeg.

Comment: For compatability with Windows Explorer, the plugin provides the`id3v2.3` option which may be set to true. See the documentation of `ffmetadata`.

Comment: is there a package to that will allow me to edit the metadata of any file type?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there's a way to actually do the meta data manipulation in NodeJS. This is a work around way but you could do this using `child_process.exec` and perl:

### [NodeJS Code](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('perl changeTags.pl file.mp3',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

### [Perl code](https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/5148211)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MP3::Tag;

$mp3 = MP3::Tag->new(@ARGV[0]); # create object 

$mp3->get_tags(); # read tags

print "Attempting to print tags for @ARGV[0]\n";

if (exists $mp3->{ID3v2}) {
  print "Comments: " . $mp3->{ID3v2}->comment . "\n";
    print "Zip: " . $mp3->{ID3v2}->album . "\n";
    print "Tags: " . $mp3->{ID3v2}->title . "\n";
} else {
    print "@ARGV[0] does not have ID3v2 tags\n";
}

$mp3->close(); # destroy object
```

Something like that. You'd obviously want to give more arguments for what you actually want to change the meta data to.... Good luck!

Comment: Why in the world did this get a down-vote?

Comment: maybe because it is in perl ;-)

Comment: -1 because is not a native node module but a workaround instead

Comment: ffmpeg isn't a native node module either...

Answer (score 0):

So far i found [jsmediatags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags) is best `npm` package to read `ID3v2` tags

```
var jsmediatags = require("jsmediatags");

jsmediatags.read("./song.mp3", {
  onSuccess: function(tag) {
    console.log(tag);
  },
  onError: function(error) {
    console.log(':(', error.type, error.info);
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work well, but supports only a basic subset of tags.

Comment: is there a package to that will allow me to edit the metadata of any file type?