# change author of mp3 file

Tags: node.js, metadata, mp3

I'd like to set the author of a mp3 file based on the data sent by the user.

So far, I managed to get the data sent by the user (hardly an exploit anyway), but I can't manage to change the author of the file. I've tried using both [node-id3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-id3) package and [ffmetadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmetadata) package, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994432/7059810), but none of this worked.

**The node-id3 approach**

Here is a part of code that I wrote for the node-id3 approach, and whille the tags shown in `readTags` are indeed the ones that I added in the `update` method,  it doesn't change the author of the file when I read it on my computer (with itunes) or on my android phone (with samsung music), which means this approach doesn't work.

```
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3')    

//getting the filename and fileAuthor, as well as creating the file on the server

let tags = {
    title: filename,
    composer: fileAuthor,
    artist: fileAuthor,
    remixArtist: fileAuthor,
    conductor: fileAuthor,
    originalArtist: fileAuthor,
}

let success = NodeID3.update(tags, toBeDownloadedFilePath)

console.log(success)

let readTags = NodeID3.read(toBeDownloadedFilePath)

console.log(readTags)
```

**the ffmetadata approach**

Here is the same part written with the ffmetadata approach :

```
const ffmetadata = require("ffmetadata");  

//getting the filename and fileAuthor, as well as creating the file on the server

let tags = {
    artist: fileAuthor,
}

ffmetadata.write(toBeDownloadedFilePath, tags, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error("Error writing metadata", err);
    else console.log("Data written");
});
```

and with this approach, I'm getting the error :

> [mp3 @ 0x7f90f8000000] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
>   [mp3 @ 0x7f90f8000000] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.
>   music1.mp3: Invalid argument

(`music1.mp3` being my filename), and my mp3 file is perfectly recognised by all audio reader with which I tested it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found where was the problem (at least with the node-id3 approach) :

to better understand it, I'll add some details to the *creating the file on server* step.

Here was my unfunctional code :

```
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3') 
const fs = require('fs-extra');  // file system   

fs.ensureFileSync(toBeDownloadedFilePath); //because I need to create the file if it doesn't exist
const toBeDownloadedFile = fs.createWriteStream(toBeDownloadedFilePath);

//the way the audio stream is created isn't relevant, but if you're interested, it's a youtube stream, as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-audio-stream
let fileWriteStream = audioStream.pipe(toBeDownloadedFile)

let tags = {
    title: filename,
    composer: fileAuthor,
    artist: fileAuthor,
    remixArtist: fileAuthor,
    conductor: fileAuthor,
    originalArtist: fileAuthor,
}

let success = NodeID3.update(tags, toBeDownloadedFilePath)

console.log(success)

let readTags = NodeID3.read(toBeDownloadedFilePath)

console.log(readTags)
```

And the problem was that my tags were written but immediately deleted by the `audiostream.pipe`

the solution was therefore quite simple, and I ended up with this code :

```
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3') 
const fs = require('fs-extra');  // file system   

fs.ensureFileSync(toBeDownloadedFilePath); //because I need to create the file if it doesn't exist
const toBeDownloadedFile = fs.createWriteStream(toBeDownloadedFilePath);

let fileWriteStream = audiSstream.pipe(toBeDownloadedFile)

fileWriteStream.on('finish', () => {
    let tags = {
        title: filename,
        artist: fileAuthor,
    }

    NodeID3.update(tags, toBeDownloadedFilePath)

    //any additional action, in my case, send the file for a download
})
```

Hope this helps people with similar problem.